# get all array values by unserialize() function with mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

how i get all values of $userid and $username from this array

`a:1:{s:2:"cc";a:2:{i:4;s:4:"koko";i:8;s:4:"soso";}}`

my code only print last string , i want get all values as array , and print all values on loop

```
$touser = array();
$sql = $db->query_read("SELECT touserarray FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . " pmtext where pmtextid = 147 ");
while ($sql1 = $db->fetch_array($sql)) 
{ 

    $touser = unserialize($sql1['touserarray']);
    foreach($touser AS $key => $item)
    {
        if (is_array($item))
        {
            foreach($item AS $subkey => $subitem)
            {
                $username = $subitem;
                $userid = $subkey;
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            $username = $item;
            $userid = $key[$i];
        }
    }
}
echo $username .'<br />'. $userid ;
```

when i print $username and $userid
only print last name and last id
// output
username : `soso`
userid : `8`

Comment: You're not saving your values anywhere...

Comment: @ialarmedalien okay i edit my code `echo $username .'<br />'. $userid ;`

Comment: Why don't you just put the `echo` inside the loop?

Comment: @Barmar becouse i print it on a template , anyway i found a good answer , thnx brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print or store your data, you'll need to create a new data structure for it. If you just want to print off the data, you need to do it in the loop where you set `$username` and `$userid`; otherwise the values will get overwritten each time the loop runs.

```
# create an array for storing user names and IDs.
$user_arr = array();

foreach($touser as $key => $item)
{
    if (is_array($item))
    {
        foreach($item AS $subkey => $subitem)
        {
            $username = $subitem;
            $userid = $subkey;
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        $username = $item;
        $userid = $key[$i];
    }
    # store the data as $user_arr[$id] = $name
    $user_arr[$userid] = $username;
    # or if you just want to print off the data during the loop...
    echo "ID: $userid; name: $username" . PHP_EOL;
}

foreach ($user_arr as $k => $v) {
    echo "id: $k; name: $v" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
id: 4; name: koko
id: 8; name: soso
```

Comment: okay i saved all data by `$all .= "id: $k; name: $v" . PHP_EOL;` , it's works a good , now if i want save all `$userid` only on `array` or `$username` how i do that ?

Comment: You already have all the usernames and the user IDs in `$user_arr` (the IDs are the keys, the names are the values); you can use `array_keys($user_arr)` or `array_values($user_arr)` to access just the IDs or just the names.

Comment: okay , so `array_keys($user_arr)` or `array_values($user_arr)` will print ALL VALUES like ARAAY `(soso,koko,elc.)` , THNX BROTHER :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving values anywhere, so `userid` and `username` overwrites every time.
Try this:

```
<?php
    $touser = array();
    $sql = $db->query_read("SELECT touserarray FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . " pmtext
                        where pmtextid = 147 ");
    while ($sql1 = $db->fetch_array($sql)) {
        $touser = unserialize($sql1['touserarray']);
        foreach($touser AS $key => $item) {
            if (is_array($item)) {
                foreach($item AS $subkey => $subitem) {
                    $username = $subitem;
                    $userid = $subkey;
                    echo $userid . '/' . $username;
                }
            }
            else {
                $username = $item;
                $userid = $key;
                echo $userid . '/' . $username;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: i put var `$username` and var `$userid` on a template , so i cannot save by `echo` on code .

Answer (score 0):

Your serialized array have this form:

```
array(1) {
  'cc' =>
  array(2) {
    [4] =>
    string(4) "koko"
    [8] =>
    string(4) "soso"
  }
}
```

You need to iterate one more (itemCC for the "cc" key):

```
    foreach ($touser as $itemCC) {
        foreach ($itemCC AS $key => $item) {
            if (is_array($item)) {
                foreach ($item AS $subkey => $subitem) {
                    $username = $subitem;
                    $userid = $subkey;
                }
            } else {
                $username = $item;
                $userid = $key;
            }
            $result[$userid] = $username;
        }
    }

// print result
foreach ($result as $userId => $username) {
    echo  $userId . " " . $username  . "<br />\n";
}
```

For example, $result variable is an array of this form userid => $username.